# How do i change the background text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Twhiter</h1>
<!-- Display Value from Text Input-->
<p id="demo"></p>
<!-- Get value from user -->
<input
placeholder="Write Your Tweet Here"
type="text"
id="tweetText"
value=""
name="tweet"
/>
<!-- Error Message-->
<small id="error"></small>
<!--Handle Click to call the function -->
<button onclick="myTweet()">
Twhit!
</button>
</div>
<script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Help me out pls i'm stuck with this code . just help me to figure the problem.... i can't really tell what is the problem. Thanks . My.js file is below

```
function myTweet() [
var tweetValue = document.getElementById(tweetText).Value;
var tweetCount = tweetValue.length;
var errorMsg = 
]
// myTweet();
```

Comment: Could you show your index.js please?

Comment: Please show us your js code and explain better what is your issue

Comment: Your function must be like this _function myTweet() { //your code }_ But explain better what do you want, actually your function do nothing. Also read [ask]

Comment: What do you want to do? At least specify the what you want from your function

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the wrong brackets for your function. Javascript functions are built this way:

```
function someFunction () {
    // do something
}
```

Your initialization of the variable errorMsg is also incomplete, you should give it a value.

Change your js file based on this, it should look like this:

```
    function myTweet() {
        var tweetValue = document.getElementById(tweetText).Value;
        var tweetCount = tweetValue.length;
        var errorMsg = "";
    }
// myTweet();
```

Comment: This is not an answer....please post it as a commenti

Comment: @Sfili_81 I would love to, but I do not have enough reputation. I edited it though, correcting his js.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color for the HTML above you can use

```
<body style="background-color:grey;">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are newbie to JavaScript as neither your syntax is correct nor is your approach, but still here your demanded code -

```js
function myTweet() {
  document.getElementById("tweetText").value = "error";
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Twhiter</h1>
<!-- Display Value from Text Input-->
<p id="demo"></p>
<!-- Get value from user -->
<input
placeholder="Write Your Tweet Here"
type="text"
id="tweetText"
value=""
name="tweet"
/>
<!--Handle Click to call the function -->
<button onclick="myTweet()">
Twhit!
</button>
</div>
<script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code you can change the value to "error" on click.

Btw, you can check this link for [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp)